# why the size of FILE structure instance is 216 bytes in 64 bit os and 148 Bytes in 32 bit os?

Tags: c, file, data-structures, file-handling

If I print the size of `FILE` or `FILE` instance then the results are 216 Bytes in 
64 Bit system and 148 Bytes in 32 Bit system (OS : Ubuntu 16.04 , compile :GCC)

```
 printf("size : %zu",sizeof(FILE));
```

OR

```
FILE *fp;
printf("size : %zu",sizeof(*fp));
```

can anyone explain why it is showing this much size , as I checked the structure members are mostly pointers .

Comment: The implementation's internal format for `FILE` notwithstanding (you shoudn't have to care) why are you using `%d` for printing a `size_t` expression? That should be `%zu`. And if the members are "mostly pointers" consider that each pointer in a 32bit vs 64bit representation will literally *double* in size going from the former to the latter.

Comment: @WhozCraig , thanks for reply , here format specifier doesn't playing any important role , both are showing the same result .

Comment: It most certainly does play an important role. Using the wrong format specifier is basically *lying* to `printf`, and invokes *undefined behavior* if/when the arguments are not of the precise type expected by the corresponding specifier. There's enough UB in the coding world; no reason to add to it with trivialities, especially when they're simple enough to just do the correct thing in the first place. Ex: if `size_t` and `int` are 64 and 32 bit respectively on your architecture (most 64bit arches are such), then you'd be shoving a 64bit value to a function expecting a 32bit value.

Comment: I checked with %zu and updated the same , thank you .

Comment: BTW, in practice, a `FILE` takes much more resources: some buffer (kilobytes) and a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (resource known to the operating system kernel)

Comment: Why do you ask? What difference does it make? Is this question to satisfy your curiosity or to solve some problem? – and if so, please share the real problem you’re trying to solve, as the answer to the size of the `FILE` structure is most definitely not the one you need to solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: Which values did you expect and why?

Comment: What size difference did you expect? What is the difference of the size of the contained elements?

Answer (score 4):

> the results are 216 Bytes in 64 Bit system and 148 Bytes in 32 Bit system
>
> can anyone explain why it is showing this much size , as I checked the structure members are mostly pointers .

The contents of `FILE` structure are implementation-specific (which means they are different in different platforms).

On a 32-bit system, the size of a pointer is usually 4 bytes and on a 64-bit system the size of a pointer is usually 8 bytes.

So the difference in the size you see (216 - 148 = 68) can be easily accounted for. (From what I remember this structure has about 15 pointers in Ubuntu GCC).
And apart from pointers the sizes of other types like `int`, `long` (which can be part of `FILE` structure) etc can differ from 32 and 64 bits systems.

Including @MatteoItalia comments below:

In particular, using [this definition](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h.html) from glibc (and `_IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE` undefined) I do get 148 bytes (with 4-byte int, pointers, `size_t` and `__off_t`).

As for the difference, there are more than 17 pointers (plus padding!) which would account for the difference, but there's also some explicit padding at the end that complicates the calculation (it does become smaller on 64 bit, as `15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)` is 40 on 32 bit, but 24 on 64 bit)

Comment: thank you , I got your point about difference between 32bit and 64 bit system . Now can you please explain why the size is 148 for 32 bit os.

Comment: @new_learner because there's 148 byte of data in there? It's really implementation-specific, depending from your system headers; dig them up from your compiler includes directory, sum up the fields sizes (taking padding in account) and you'll see that it'll add up to 148.

Comment: In particular, using [this definition](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h.html) from glibc (and `_IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE` undefined) I do get 148 bytes (with 4-byte `int`, pointers, `size_t` and `__off_t`).

Comment: As for the difference, there are more than 17 pointers (plus padding!) which would account for the difference, but there's also some explicit padding at the end that complicates the calculation (it does become smaller on 64 bit, as `15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)` is 40 on 32 bit, but 24 on 64 bit).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Can I include your comments in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The contents and size of the `FILE` structure is entirely specific to the implementation. it happens to be 216 bytes on your OS in 64-bit mode and 148 in 32-bit mode. The difference could come from the differing sizes of some of the members of this structure between 32-bit and 64-bit mode: pointers are larger, as well as `size_t` and file positions, it really depends on how the C library handles the standard streams.

Note that some extra information might be stored outside the structure... in any case you cannot save a `FILE` to a local variable and restore it safely.

Note that `FILE` could also be an incomplete type: a `typedef` for a pointer to a structure whose definition is absent, in which case `sizeof(FILE)` would cause a compilation error. The main reason to put the definition in the `<stdio.h>` header is to allow macros to access members directly. Take a look into your `<stdio.h>` file and look for other implementations in open source, such as the newlib or the glibc.

Furthermore, the C Standard does not mandate that `FILE` be a `typedef` for a structure: it might not be a structure, it could be defined as an `int`.

Comment: @Note that FILE might not be a structure at all. It could be defined as an int . FILE is a typedefed structure : typedef struct  _IO_FILE  FILE ; (typedefed in stdio.h and declared in libio.h)

Comment: @new_learner *FILE is a typedefed structure : typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE ; (typedefed in stdio.h and declared in libio.h)* That's true only for the one implementation you looked at.  There are others - **many** others.